# How to update Mysql entry using Playframework

Tags: playframework

I'm writing a TodoList application using Playframework. I want to update a task but don't know **how to update** with JPA (I'm just moving from PHP with Zend Framework and don't familiar with Hibernate). 
I have edit page with URL for example: http://localhost:9000/TaskList/edit?id=2

Its controller:

```
public static void edit(Long id) {
        models.TaskList selectedTask = models.TaskList.findById(id);
        render(selectedTask);
    }
```

Its model

```
@Entity
public class TaskList extends Model {

public String task;
public int priority;
public String category;
public String taskStatus;

public TaskList(String task, int priority, String category, String taskStatus) {
    this.task = task;
    this.priority = priority;
    this.category = category;
    this.taskStatus = taskStatus;
}
```

Do I need id property in the model (in database, I have id field)?
If not, how to update when the model doesn't specify the id?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define an id as the id is given by play.db.jpa.Model class.
Yet, if you want to define your own id, you can replace the `extends Model` by `extends GenericModel` and then you redefine your own @Id field such as (this is the code of Model class):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long id;
```

Anyway, as you can see in the previous 3 lines of code, the Id by default a generated value. So you don't care about its value as it's given by the database when you first persist your object.

Now if you want to update your object, do:

```
public static void edit(Long id) {
        // get your object
        models.TaskList selectedTask = models.TaskList.findById(id);
        // modify your object
        selectedTask.something = somevalue;
        // update your object
        selectedTask.save();
        // finally render your updated selectedTask
        render(selectedTask);
    }
```

That's all ;)

Comment: You're welcome and if you're fed up with JPA, give a try to alternative such as Siena, it can give sometimes a whiff of oxygen ;)